# ASP.Net MVC - Need to pass part of the View Model into POST Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

So, I have a form that has a corresponding domain class.  My page's view model however, contains that domain class and other information such as drop down list data sources.  In addition, my view model has no parameterless contructor.

Now, when I try to do a post method (i.e., save the data), the view model is what's being passed.  Is there a way for me to just pass the domain object as that's what I only care about?

If not, how do you guys structure your page to rectify this?

Thanks.

Comment: please, provide the code, so we will know what You've tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

Just make sure that the fields that represent the model that you are interested in are the only ones wrapped inside the form. As long as the names are correct and all required fields are there, then you're good. Also, make sure that the actionmethod parameter is of the same type as the model that you are after, rather than of the viewmodel type!!

Answer (score 0):

Use as view model the model you need to pass when submit. Pass the rest of the information to the view using ViewData.

Comment: I did try to do this, but it does not seem to be an elegant solution.  The view I have is used in many parts and it has a tendency to evolve through time.  If I can do away with having to remember which ViewData  properties I have to fill every time I reference it somewhere else on my project, that would be great.